# Find duplicates in a list of pairs

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to implement a kind of dictionaries as data structure in OCaml, for didactical purpose. When creating a new dict, I can pass a list of pairs `[(key:value);...]` to initialize the dict, but, before inserting them in the dict, I should check if each key (in the list) is unique. How I can achive this?

This is what I've done:

```
| Dict(initList) ->
    let rec evaluateList (initList : (ide * exp) list) (env : evT env) : (ide * evT) list =
        match initList with
            | [] -> []
            | (key, value)::t -> (key, eval value env)::(evaluateList t env)
    in DictValue(evaluateList initList env)
```

`DictValue` is a reprasentable type for dict.

Example of input:

```
let myDict = Dict([
    ("apple",   Eint(430));
    ("banana", Eint(312));
]);; (* Ok *)

let myDictWrong = Dict([
    ("apple", Eint(12));
    ("apple", Eint(13))
]);; (* Wrong *)
```

Edit: So, the situation is that I'm writing a kind of interpreter, that have a function `eval` like

```
let rec eval (e : exp) (environment : evT env) : evT = match e with
    | ...
    .
    .
    | Dict(initList) ->
    let rec evaluateList (initList : (ide * exp) list) (env : evT env) : (ide * evT) list =
        match initList with
            | [] -> []
 (*here*)   | (key, value)::t -> (key, eval value env)::(evaluateList t env)
    in DictValue(evaluateList initList env)
```

As said in comments, I can maybe check the key, in line (*here*), directly in the dict that I'm creating, but I don't know how to achive this.

Comment: You are already building a Dict, before inserting a new entry ask the Dict if the key already exist?

Comment: I don't know how to access to the Dict that I'm building in my code, because I'm already in a pattern-matching statements and I've a structure like `let rec evaluateList ... in DictValue`, this one is the Dict but, again, I don't know how to use this. I already have a `HasKey` function, but it need a Dict as argument.

Comment: Something like `| (key, value)::t -> let dict = (evaluateList t env) in if List.mem key dict then raise "duplicate key" else (key, eval value env)::dict`

Answer (score 0):

> before inserting them in the dict, I should check if each key (in the list) is unique. How I can achive this?

With a very simple helper function?

Your "key is unique" can be expressed in another way: a key X does not exist in the list at the moment you're adding it. Right?

So, how would one check if the key exists already? The key exists if it equal to the one in a head element of the list OR it exists in the list's tail. Do you see this recursive pattern? So, the implementation literally follows the description:

```
let rec is_member key = function
  | [] -> false
  | (k, _)::tail ->
    if k = key then true
    else is_member key tail
;;

is_member "foo" [("foo", 1); ("bar", 2); ("baz", 3)];;
- : bool = true

is_member "foo" [("not-a-foo", 1); ("bar", 2); ("baz", 3)];;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: Or just `k = key || is_member key tail`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you've created is an [association list](https://ocaml.org/docs/lists#association-lists). For small data sets this works just fine.

The `List` module already contains a function `mem_assoc` which determines if a key is in the association list. If we want to determine if a duplicate key exists, we would recursively check if the head key in the list occurs elsewhere in the list. Done without any `List` module functions for demonstration:

```
let rec has_dup_key = function
  | [] -> false
  | (k, _)::tl ->
    let rec aux k = function
      | [] -> false
      | (k', _)::tl -> k = k' || aux k tl
    in
    aux k tl || has_dup_key tl
```

But this is pretty inefficient. More efficient is to use a map, which in OCaml internally uses a balanced binary tree. We can iterate over the keys in an association list. For each key, if a binding for it already exists in the map, we'll return `true` as this indicates a duplicate key. Otherwise we'll create the binding and call the function on the tail recursively.

```
module StringMap = Map.Make (String)

let has_dup_key lst = 
  let rec aux map = function
    | [] -> false
    | (k, _)::tl when StringMap.mem k map -> true
    | (k, _)::tl -> aux (StringMap.add k 1 map) tl
  in
  aux StringMap.empty lst
```